# A LiPo battery protection circuit IV

Tags: lipo

Sorry, trying to get the hang of this site. I'll try this one more time.
Could the circuit in the previous post (schematic and link below) be adapted to cut off a 13,200 mAh 11.7 volt battery running at 3 amps full power for an LED light similar to the one also in the link below? What would be a suitable cutoff voltage? People are leaving the power on and running the LiPo dead. An auto cutoff modification, like the one shown, would be a great addition to the original lamp design.

[A Lipo battery protection circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279696/a-lipo-battery-protection-circuit/625347?noredirect=1#comment1652514_625347)

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2255799854674302.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend these modifications (not tested):

1. Use TLVH 431 because TLV 431 is only specified up to 6 V
2. Use a thermally more robust P-FET as Q1 (e.g. 2SJ652-RA11)
3. Assumed this is a 3S LiPo battery, use a cut off voltage of 9.6 V.
4. Add a resistor of around 15 Mohm between ADJ pin of IC1 and the load output (drain of Q1) to produce a hysteretic behavior.

Resistor calculation is R1 = R2 * ((Ubat / Upin1) - 1), set here R2 = 100 kohm

R1 = 100 kohm * ((9.6 V / 1.24 V) - 1) = 674 kohm, take 680 kohm

This circuit will continue to slowly drain the battery even after turn off like most BMS do. It must be recharged within some weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the circuit shown in that old question will work. You will need to change the components to work with your "11.7 V" battery (Meaning it is probably a **3S** battery.)

I would recommend that you just buy something like this [Voltage Protection Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QNXM4LS) and set it to 11.2V.

The 11.2V comes from the 80/20 rule for LiPo batteries and shown in [this handy chart](https://blog.ampow.com/lipo-voltage-chart/) where the "3S" section shows 20% is around 11.18V.